# Can't install webdriveragent-runner on iOS real device

Tags: ios, facebook, appium

I have two machines:

- macbook pro and mac mini

I installed and ran WDA at own iPhone without any problems from macbook. But from the mac mini, I couldn't do it.

Trusted certificate with good provision profile, app (WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app) was install, but crashed with this error:

```
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: cr_update: <private>
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash[489] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[488] <private>
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(MobileCoreServices)[489] <Notice>: notify_register_check() failed with error 1000000
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[123] <Notice>: 488 com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner: Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[123] <Notice>: Entry, display name com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner uuid (null) pid 488 isFront 0
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[123] <Notice>: Duplicate removal of display name com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Info>: scanned 152 logs with 11 types and 10 unknowns (sentinel is <private>)
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Report of type '109(<private>)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Process:             XCTRunner [488]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/63E4047A-DAD9-4B64-BE1F-AA4F1599C08D/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/XCTRunner
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0 (14A346)
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/63E4047A-DAD9-4B64-BE1F-AA4F1599C08D/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/XCTRunner | Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/63E4047A-DAD9-4B64-BE1F-AA4F1599C08D/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/63E4047A-DAD9-4B64-BE1F-AA4F1599C08D/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest'
Triggered by Thread:  0
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00000001000e5cd8 0x1000c0000 + 154840
1   dyld                            0x00000001000e5668 0x1000c0000 + 153192
2   dyld                            0x00000001000e56b0 0x1000c0000 + 153264
3   dyld                            0x00000001000c4514 0x1000c0000 + 17684
4   dyld                            0x00000001000c69a8 0x1000c0000 + 27048
5   dyld                            0x00000001000c1044 0x1000c0000 + 4164
May  3 21:25:40 iPhone ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[489] <Notice>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x000000016fd76170   x3: 0x00000000000000a5
x4: 0x000000016fd75d70   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000000000006d0
x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000009  x10: 0x612e72656e6e7552  x11: 0x656d6172462f7070
x12: 0x582f736b726f7765  x13: 0x72662e7473655443  x14: 0x2f6b726f77656d61  x15: 0x0027747365544358
x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x00000000000bc000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
x20: 0x000000016fd75d70  x21: 0x00000000000000a5  x22: 0x000000016fd76170  x23: 0x0000000000000001
x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x00000001000f1ab8  x26: 0x00000001000f3bb8  x27: 0x4df3b83aa4ff0050
x28: 0x00000001000f1000   fp: 0x000000016fd75d40   lr: 0x00000001000e5668
sp: 0x000000016fd75d00   pc: 0x00000001000e5cd8 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

When started WDA UITests:

```
2017-05-03 14:39:01.130 xcodebuild[2732:11442] Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-12 "Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to launch com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc37d959960 {Error Domain=DTXMessage Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={DTXExceptionKey=The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 3.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.apple.test.WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner'}}}
2017-05-03 14:39:01.130 xcodebuild[2732:11442] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

Testing failed: Test target WebDriverAgentRunner encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted)
** TEST FAILED **
```

My environment:

- xcode 8.2.1
- iOS 10.0
- node 7.9.0
- npm 4.2.0
- carthage 0.22.0
- libimobiledevice HEAD

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue by re-downloading the WWDR (Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority) and set its trust: 'use system default'.

Download from here: http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: Where to put this file after downloading